# about undocumented parameter for AC_INIT

Tags: autoconf

what does parameter 'move-if-change' stands for in AC_INIT()?
I've read the documentation of AC_INIT but it is mentioned nowhere.
And also read the manual page for 'autoconf' but no chance, it wasn't
described there.

The code that I'm reviewing is bellow.

> AC_INIT(move-if-change)
>
> AC_DISABLE_OPTION_CHECKING

:NOTE:
I could not make it to work on 2.69 it keep asking for version 2.64, 
I'm trying to compile crossgcc for coreboot. And I delete the line AC_PREQ
line between them but it still keep asking for 2.64.

Comment: The manual for `autoconf` at [Initializing `configure`](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Initializing-configure) shows `AC_INIT` with two mandatory and 3 optional arguments: `AC_INIT (package, version, [bug-report], [tarname], [url])`.  Thus your initialization seems to be out of date.  Nominally, 'move-if-change' is the package name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the old version of Autoconf (up to 2.13), `AC_INIT` had only one calling syntax:

```
AC_INIT(filename)
```

where `filename` was the name of a file in the source directory.  This file would be used by `./configure` to make sure that the directory it thinks is the source directory is actually the source directory.  Today this syntax is obsolete (and has been for over 10 years).  You should move away from it.

A more modern setup would be:

```
AC_INIT([package-name], [version])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([move-if-change])
```